# Reusing a Require.js shim config between pages

Tags: requirejs

I am interested in creating a single configuration object for all the JavaScript code on my Web site. I found https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim which is an example of this setup.

> From https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim (emphasis
>   mine): Since the shim config requires dependencies to be in the page,
>   instead of using data-main="js/page1" for page1.html, this example
>   inlines the require calls in the HTML page. **If data-main was used
>   instead, then 'js/page1' could not have any dependencies inlined**,
>   and instead still rely on the 'common' and 'app/main1' build layers to
>   hold the modules, due to the restrictions shim config places on the
>   build.

I do not understand the bolded sentence. Does it mean that "js/page1" if it existed could not declare dependencies? What does it mean to have a dependency inlined? Inlined into what? The HTML file or the JavaScript file?

I read the API doc about shim config, but the limitations that it puts on the optimizer is not clear.

From https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim/blob/master/www/page1.html:

```
    <script src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Load common code that includes config, then load the app
        //logic for this page. Do the require calls here instead of
        //a separate file so after a build there are only 2 HTTP
        //requests instead of three.
        require(['./js/common'], function (common) {
            //js/common sets the baseUrl to be js/ so
            //can just ask for 'app/main1' here instead
            //of 'js/app/main1'
            require(['app/main1']);
        });
    </script>
```

Why is the following wrong? Why does "app/main1" have to be in a separate module from the bootstrap (data-main) code?

```
    <script src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
    <script>
        require(['js/common'], function (common) {
            var underscore = require('underscore');
            // ...
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good practice to define (with define) each module in a separate javascript file. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to load the several modules asynchronuously, because the are in the same physical location. In most cases, you'll only need to use function define. Only in your bootstrapping module, you'll need to use function require.

When I'm using require.js, I have 1 module (bootstrap.js), which contains my require.config object and the initial bootstrapping. In the html page you only need to include 1 script: require.js with bootstrap as data-main attribute value:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="js/lib/require.js" data-main="bootstrap"></script>
```

**bootstrap:**

```
require.config = {
   baseUrl: 'js',
   paths: {
     ...
   },
   shim: {
   }
   ...
};

// initial bootstrap
require(['jquery', 'angular', 'app'], function($, angular) {
   // do bootstrap
});
```

**Modules:**

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
   // do sth with app
});
```

**Edit:** misunderstood the question a bit.

The reason that you cannot use inline dependencies in the html page when using the data-main attribute is that it like likely fail to load them. Which code block will be executed first? The data-main bootstrapping js or the inline code? If your bootstrapping js file will load first and set the `baseUrl` to `'js'`, the inline code should use `require('common')` instead of `require('js/common')`. But if the inline code loads first, it has to be `require('js/common')`.

The reason why `require('app/main1')` is inside the other require block is the same: module 'common' will change the baseUrl to `'js'`. Also *'app/main'* probably needs some of the shim config from *'common'*. This is the only way to make sure the common module (with the shim config) is loaded first.

Comment: This isn't an answer to my question. I am asking about the limitations that using the shim config option puts on the optimizer. Specifically I want to know why `require(['app/main1'])` is needed inside of the bootstrap `require()` call. See https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage. In that project the shim config option is not used and the nested `require()` call is not used. The question is why.

Comment: I've added a extra section to my answer. That is the way I interpret the answer to your first question.

Comment: There are 2 issues I can see. The first is what you addressed about `baseUrl` and the way the paths are written. I don't really understand why `baseUrl` is nice to use because I prefer my import statements to be absolute so I choose not to use `baseUrl`.

Comment: The second issue is with the way the optimizer combines files. As I understand it the optimizer needs the config so it knows where the best place is to inline the shimmed code. When the optimizer is not used, this doesn't matter and the nested `require()` call is not needed because declaring a dependency on a shim will trigger a download of the shimmed code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only real solution to avoid duplicating your shims may be a combination of server side templates and a build processor like grunt.js.

You'll only need the server side template part if you want to ever switch between the optimized require.js load and the non-optimized mode (like for development purposes).

1. Define a single JavaScript file that has your shared shim in it.
2. If using grunt.js use node `export` syntax to export your shim and paths.
3. Require it as part of your grunt config. Either write require.js config files or depending 
   on the grunt plugin you may be able to just get away with reusing the `require`'ed 
   config in memory as part of your require.js build.
4. As part of your grunt build write a server template file used by your backend
   architecture.  For example if you are using django, write a partial django template that 
   isn't  checked into the repository. Probably include the output path in your .gitignore
   if you are using .git.
5. In your index.html or initial load the partial as a global variable before your require.js
   script tag with the data-main when not using optimized shims. In your `requirejs` call
   set or extend your requirejs.config with the data you loaded in from the template into
   Javascript.

A less optimal, but simpler solution might be to simply set a global variable that defines the executing context and then load a shared entry `requirejs` script that then uses a `switch` on your context variable to call `require` at runtime depending on the context. This may be more difficult to optimize. Even less optimally you could just always require everything needed for all your pages and use this context to figure out what to run instead of what to require, but obviously then you are always loading all your JavaScript. This may work in the context of a browser extension, although could still slow things down with all that unecessary JavaScript being processed.

Having said all this, it would be nice if requirejs provided a way to load a config that is separate from a `requirejs` or `define` call, simply to avoid the case of having the same shims declared all over the place.

Comment: This is what I've done. I build my main.js files, by injecting the config into each.  Then, in my r.js config, I define modules for each.

Answer (score 0):

When you use **shim** config, add a matching **paths** config property for each shim that you wish to be asynchronously loadable:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        backbone: 'lib/backbone',
        jquery: 'lib/jquery',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore'
    },
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});
```

The shim modules can then be used as dependencies in `define()` like any other real module. (At least that's my experience!)

Comment: This answer doesn't address any of my questions.

Comment: Hekevintran, you are making RequireJS more complicated than it needs to be. This answer shows a simpler strategy.

Comment: I understand how to use the shim and path config options. This works fine **if you do not use the Require.js optimizer**. What you wrote does not address how it can guarantee that the shimmed code will be loaded before the code in `data-main` **if I use the optimizer**. If it does, please explain.

Comment: In my experience using this approach of **paths** & **shim**, the optimizer does correctly order the shimmed modules. The reason it doesn't order them correctly for you, is because you're using `require()` inside the module function, instead of using the `define([dependencies])` argument. ...or perhaps I misunderstand your problem.

Comment: The example is from the author of Require.js.  His config and the shimmed code are in `common`.  As I understand it, if you were to write something like `define(['common', 'underscore'], ...)` you cannot guarantee that `common` (which contains underscore) would be loaded first. Trying to load `underscore` first is wrong because it is not defined until `common` is loaded.

Comment: Guess I've been lucky with three different Ember + RequireJS apps. Sorry it's such a pain for you.